# Using newline/page break tag in ArcGIS Desktop Text_Element in arcpy.mapping?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, newline

I want to update a Text_Element with a newline or page break using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Does anyone know the tag or syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [second example in the online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000000m000000) demonstrates how to add the newline to a text element.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I was trying /n and <br/> and all that stuff. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 3):

Dan is correct (and answered before me), but I had to try this myself, as I assumed that there was no way that a `\n` would work (that would be too easy!)

I made a textbox, named it "Text", added some text:

[image]

Ran this code that Dan points to:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
>>> elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Text")[0]
>>> elm.text = 'Date: <dyn type="date" format="short"/> \nTime: <dyn type="time" format=""/>'
>>> arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

And got this:

[image]

Also, this seems to only work programmatically; adding a `\n` in the textbox in ArcMap only outputs the \n as text.

Comment: You should use `\r\n` instead of just `\n`, otherwise it can cause TextElements to bug out. See [this question I asked a few months ago](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17368/inserting-newlines-in-rectangle-text-elements-via-arcpy-causes-overlap).

Comment: @dmahr - Interesting, thanks for pointing that out.