# ArcPy-generated string formats badly in map text element

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, layouts, element

I've got a script that's pulling a bunch of attributes and concatenating the information into a long string.

```
text_description = "Address: {}\n\n".format(dictADDR[key])
text_description += "{} Customers.".format(len(listCustomer))
if countPole == 0:
    text_description += "No Poles\n"
else:
    text_description += "Poles:\n"
    text_description += "  Pole Quantity: {}\n".format(countPole)
(et cetera)
```

The goal is to include this string both in an emailed final report when the script finishes, and include it in a text element on a PDF map (displayed next to the parcel and an aerial map).

This works fine for the email, and gives something like:

```
Address:  1225 BICKLEY RD
0 Customers
No Poles
No Overhead Distribution
```

However, in the text element it ends up ignoring spacing and overlaps some text with other text (see image below).

[image]

Copy-pasting the contents of the text properties box, it appears to have the line breaks in the correct places:

`Address:  1225 BICKLEY RD
0 Customers.
No Poles
No Electric Overhead Distribution`

What's going wrong, and what should I change in either the text element or my code to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the text reported in the text element properties (double-click on the text element)?

Comment: @phloem Same as the string that's showing up in the email, including line breaks; I've updated the Question to include that detail. Thanks.

Comment: See this discussion (try '\r\n'): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17368/inserting-newlines-in-rectangle-text-elements-via-arcpy-causes-overlap

Comment: I'm on a roll with duplicate questions recently -- my google skills are clearly failing me. Thank you!